# Поиск элементов в массиве (паскаль)

Tags: массивы, pascal

Нужно в массиве найти ПЕРВОЕ вхождение элементов (не одного элемента, а многих) и вернуть индекс первого найденное совпадение. 
Например: 
В массиве 1,2,2,6,6,7,1,1,1,7,1 найти индекс, с которого начинается 1, 1, 1 -> результат: 6 
Как реализовать функцию?

Comment: А о числах что-нибудь известно? А то в паскале есть встроенный тип -- множества, только вот реализации ограничивают их мощность (256 элементов). Если можно использовать их, то делаем два прохода: в первом заносим элементы в о множество, во втором -- проверяем, если элемент есть -- фиксируем первое вхождение и удаляем элемент, нет -- пропускаем. Получаем список/массив/последовательный вывод первых вхождений.

Comment: Похоже я немного наврал. Видимо я был слишком хорошего мнения о TP/BP/Delphi и пр. извратах. Увы.

Comment: Посвящается фирме Borland (допустимые числа: 0..255):

    Program A;
    Const
      arr: Array [1..11] of SmallInt = (1,2,2,6,6,7,1,1,1,7,1);
    Var
      i: Integer;
      s: Set of Char;
    Begin
      s := [];
      For i := 1 to 11 Do
        Include(s, chr(arr[i]));
      For i := 1 to 11 Do
        If chr(arr[i]) in s Then Begin
            WriteLn(arr[i], ':', i);
            Exclude(s, chr(arr[i]));
        End;
    End.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// string::find
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
  std::string str2 ("needle");

  // different member versions of find in the same order as above:
  std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';

  found=str.find("needles are small",found+1,6);
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "second 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';

  found=str.find("haystack");
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "'haystack' also found at: " << found << '\n';

  found=str.find('.');
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Period found at: " << found << '\n';

  // let's replace the first needle:
  str.replace(str.find(str2),str2.length(),"preposition");
  std::cout << str << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
first 'needle' found at: 14
second 'needle' found at: 44
'haystack' also found at: 30
Period found at: 51
There are two prepositions in this haystack with needles.
```

Источник:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

рекомендую сайт положить в заметку, довольно часто меня выручает :)

Comment: а вы не заметили, что в вопросе в качестве языка указан Паскаль? Да и оперируете вы строками. а не массивами

Comment: да, не обратил внимание что речь о Паскале, ибо подписан на С++ :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 var 
    i,Otvet:integer;
    Mass:array[0..10]of integer;

...

    for i:=0 to 8 do 
    if (Mass[i]=1)and(Mass[i+1]=1)and(Mass[i+2]=1) then break;

    Otvet:=i;
```

по моему так, не отлаживал, но думаю тут всё нормально.

Comment: @yuriybuchinskiy Зря Вы так думаете. И вообще не понятно, что Вы написали.

Comment: Чего тут не понятно?... Перебор, проверяем 3 элемента, как совпали break. Текущее i и есть тот самый индекс. Если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, конкретный массив и конкретные числа даны в вопросе для примера, а решение нужно универсальное, для поиска произвольной группы чисел в произвольном массиве.